# Generating own vector tiles on OpenStreetMap with filtered layers

Tags: openstreetmap, vector-tiles, openmaptiles

I want to create my own vector tileset based on OSM free data but with filtered layers.

How I must define desired layers for my result tileset?

I have seen the link
[OpenMapTiles Vector Tile Schema Implementation](https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles) but there no description about filtering layers and customization. Prepared [world pbf file](http://Planet%20PBF%20File) contained all layers that don't suit my needs and I would like to disable some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to disable some layers you can do this in yaml file (https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles/blob/master/openmaptiles.yaml).

If you need to change a content of a layer - definitions are in layers directory (https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles/tree/master/layers), if you'll get familiar with files inside each directory you should find out what's going on there. Also I advise you to get familiar with osm tagging. Changing layer's definitions is not a simple task for a beginner and AFAIK there is no WYSIWYG or even GUI tool for this. Every single change here could significantly increase time of preparing data, tile's sizes and decrease performance... Also next thing is that I didn't found any detailed-enough documentation so I had to do everything by myself analyzing the individual files and the relations between them. I regret that I didn't made one after all, but the project has been abandoned - and now, it was some time ago and I forgot most of it...

Comment: Do you, by chance, have any ideas of editing MBtiles using SQLite DB Browser? I tried to run sql query to change mbtile dataset and it returns errors all the time.